# tsvector and tsquery not working with numbers

Tags: postgresql

I need to perform a search with the string and number as well in postgres, the search with string is working fine, but tsvector is not searching with numbers like this

```
SELECT * FROM public.tte_status
where status_name::tsvector @@ '800'::tsquery
ORDER BY id ASC
```

string search is working fine

```
SELECT * FROM public.tte_status
where status_name::tsvector @@ 'string'::tsquery
ORDER BY id ASC
```

I have data in status_name column like this

| status_name |
| --- |
| string one |
| string two |
| one string |
| two string |
| 800-1001 |
| 11/8000 |

Comment: Works for me, `SELECT '800'::tsvector @@ '800'::tsquery;` returns true.  If it doesn't work for you, you haven't given us enough information to help.  Like, what is actually in status_name which doesn't match when it should?

Comment: I have updated the data for the status_name column in the question

Comment: search with "string" is working fine, it is getting all rows containing "string", but when I try to search with 800 I am getting no results

Answer (score 1):

'800-1001' interpreted as a tsvector is a single token.  It will match to itself, not a substring of itself (unless you use ':*').

Since your input is plain text, you want to convert to tsvector with to_tsvector(), not just cast to tsvector.

The reason you see the problem only with numbers is that your example doesn't use any complex tokens like hyphenated words, except for with numbers.

Comment: I tried with to_tsvector(status_name) @@ to_tsquery('string | 80:*') still no results with rows 80 are showing up

Comment: This returns true for me: `select  to_tsvector('800-1000') @@ to_tsquery('string | 80:*') ;`.  It might depend on your default_text_search_config, but I wouldn't expect it to for this case.

Comment: Yes, this to_tsvector('800-1000') @@ to_tsquery('string | 80:*') returns true when added string directly in vector, but when you pass column in vector it is not working